# Kivy does not display Windows and there is no error in code

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I am using ubuntu 18.40 and python 3. I have installed kivy. The framework does not display any window when I run it. I am using pycharm. I have tried almost all the solution on the web but they are not working. The code does not show any error.
Code

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    # @property
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Waguitar")


if __name__ == " __main__ ":
    MyApp().run()
```

These is what I seen on

```
/home/rutherford/kivyproject/bin/python /home/rutherford/Kivy_app/app.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/rutherford/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-05-03_59.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/rutherford/kivyproject/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I dont have ubuntu so it is not easy for me to reproduce your issue, but have you already tried to set the window size manually? It can be done with the Window class: "from kivy.core.window import Window" then you use it in your build method "Window.size = (600, 400) "

Comment: I get these Error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: Which kivy version have you installed? Maybe you have corrupted your package somehow.Try to uninstall kivy (pip uninstall kivy) and reinstall it. if it uses your cached version uninstall it one more time and try it with the command "pip install --no-cached-dir kivy". Maybe this will help

Comment: If this does not help you may have some missing sdl2 dependencies as sdl2 is responsible for showing the window itself. Follow the instructions on the kivy page [link](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux-venvs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
if __name__ == " __main__ ":
```

has extra spaces inside the quotes. It should be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: It throws these error [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Comment: That is a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed these using the following command and it worked for me

```
 sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0
```